# C# Android Unhandled Exception Error System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, unhandled-exception

I am trying to get Database Data to insert into List View

Error Code:

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. occurred
```

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**[image]

Comment: please DON'T post code as images.  Take the time to post your code as properly formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

Either shMsg or sqldb is null.

Comment: How do i make it Not Null (check update)

Comment: Do you ever set that property to anything? If you but a breakpoint on the setter, does it ever get hit?

Comment: No the breakpoint never gets a hit, why would this occur

Comment: This is really basic stuff. You need to learn c# basics first. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_properties.htm

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint on line `shMsg = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.shMsg);`Then check if your resource is filled, and if you step 1 execution further, if the variable `shMsg` has a value.
Then proceed stepping until you realise which object has a `null` value.

The reason you get this exception is because you're trying to get a property of something that doesn't exist, because it's `null`.

If the `sqldb` variable is `null`, make sure you don't dispose of the connection to the database prematurely, which is a common mistake.

Comment: The breakpoint at `shMsg = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.shMsg);` is null from the beginning

Comment: Which value is null? When you hit the breakpoint, or when the exception is thrown, you can mouseover variables and check their values set.